# How to convert multi String array to string array in swift

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

var names:[[String]] = [["google"],["yahoo"],["facebook"]]

var convertNames:[String] = []

//how to convert names multi String array to convertNames String Array

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **`flatMap(_:)`**  on `names` `array` to get the required result, i.e.

```
let names = [["google"],["yahoo"],["facebook"]]

let convertNames = names.flatMap{ $0 }
print(convertNames) //["google", "yahoo", "facebook"]
```

For detailed info in `flatMap(_:)` refer link - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap